# What is the purpose of the slit in a spectroscope?

Tags: waves, experimental-physics, diffraction, spectroscopy, home-experiment

I built a spectroscope using a CD as diffraction grating. I understood how the grating works, but I didn't get why the slit is essential. Shouldn't it work even without the slit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more pedestrian answer, just in terms of angles: no slit is needed for a point source. But to take the spectrum of the light coming from an extended source (like for example a cloud) a slit is necessary. For sources like the Sun or a lamp it depends on the resolution that one wants to achieve.

The dispersive element (grating or prism) gives a certain angular spread. Light from an extended source comes in with different angles. The spectra from different incoming angles will overlap with each other. This limits the wavelength resolution after the grating.

Many monochromator beamlines at synchrotron x-ray sources can operate without an entrance slit because the source is small and relatively far away (tens of meters).

Comment: Thank you, but the main thing i do not understand is why the resolution changes with the amplitude of the slit

Comment: @CaddoShaman  Because light from a monochromatic source with different incoming angles will also come out of the grating (or prism) with different angles. This results in a width. If you consider a grating, it is about the same size as the width of the zeroth order. I would suggest that you make a drawing.

Comment: So with a slit you can make a "more straigh" light beam that when reflected  make the single monochromatic beams interfere less with each other giving a better spectrum? It is so?

Answer (score 2):

The slit is an approximation to a coherent light source. It can be considered to produce wavefronts (mathematical surfaces at all points on which the oscillations are in phase) that are continuous across the emerging beam. [The light also needs to be approximately monochromatic (single wavelength) but that's down to whatever is illuminating the slit.]

The wavefronts from the slit are rendered plane by the collimator lens, so they fall simultaneously on each slit of the grating (if you're using a plane grating at normal incidence). Thus each slit in the grating is an in-phase source in its own right, allowing you to use $d \sin \theta=n \lambda.$

Without the slit, the light from (say) a sodium vapour lamp, even though approximately monochromatic, will not be coherent. There will be no phase relationship between light originating from different regions of the vapour.

[Note that the collimator lens needs a point source on its focal plane in order to produce plane wavefronts. Strictly the slit is a line source and the wavefronts produced by the collimator lens are not truly plane, but this turns out not to be very significant.]